# How to check url status code using aiohttp?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following code to check url status code:

```
async def _is_url_ok(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return resp.status == 200
```

What is the best way to handle an exception? Is it ok to do like this?

```
async def _is_url_ok(url):
    try:
       async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
           async with session.get(url) as resp:
               return resp.status == 200
    except:
        return False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what is your target.

Sometimes you need a page content validation etc.

Anyway catching `aiohttp.ClientError` is better than bare `except`.